# How to save json response in local storage using angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have api which return json response and I want to store that json response in localstorage to use that response in my another html page using angularjs.

Here is my code which return json response....

```
QAApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.search = function (searchtag) {
           var request = $http({
                          method: 'GET', 
                          url: server + 'api/question/tagged/' + searchtag,
                        });
                request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.qa = data;
            });

        }
  });
```

Please tell me how can I store it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On your request.success(),use

```
window.localStorage['storageName'] = angular.toJson(data);
```

Then you can access the data in localstorage by

```
var accessData = window.localStorage['storageName'];
```

Comment: Yes it is working I am able to save in local storage. Can you please tell me how can I use that "storageName" in html page to display the data using angularjs.

Comment: @AnitaMehta var accessData = window.localStorage['storageName']; $scope.VarName = angular.fromJson(accessData);
so you can use the 'varname' to customize your data in HTML pages

Comment: I got the response but I am not able to display.....what I am doing is  on onclick I got the response and want to display to next page.....So after onclcik I got the data and also going to next page the data is not displaying....

Comment: var accessData = window.localStorage['storageName']; 
$scope.VarName = angular.fromJson(accessData); 
In HTML Page use 
{{VarName.<JSON string Name of Name_value_Pair>}}

Comment: use double curly braces like {{<JSON data>}}, to display data in HTML pages

Comment: yes I did like that only...I don't know why it is not display.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401603/not-able-to-displaying-json-response-on-html-page-using-angulajs....see this link I post my code here....

Answer (score 5):

I want to suggest this one because I used it and it works stable https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.

After downloading and attaching it to your project you should add it as a dependency

```
    QAApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location,$localStorage) {

      $scope.search = function (searchtag) {
               var request = $http({
                              method: 'GET', 
                              url: server + 'api/question/tagged/' + searchtag,
                            });
                    request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $localStorage.qa = datal
                    $scope.qa = data;
                });



  }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$scope.Save = angular.toJson(data); //Save to storage
sessionStorage.setItem('blablabla',$scope.Save);
localStorage.setItem('blablabla', $scope.Save); 

$scope.DataFromJson = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["blablabla"]); //Get from storage
$scope.DataFromJson = JSON.parse(localStorage["blablabla"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

/* To retrive json from localStorage */

```
var user = angular.fromJson($window.localStorage['md-user']);
```

/* To store json in loacalStorage */

```
$window.localStorage['md-user'] = angular.toJson(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To store**

```
$scope.storeItem = function() {
 sessionStorage.setItem('item', angular.toJson($scope.selectedItem));
}
```

**To retrieve**

```
$scope.retrieve = function() {
    $scope.selectedItem = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('item'));
}
```